# How to make browser back disabled in angular?

Tags: angular, browser

I am working on angular 6. I have multiple pages and I want to make the browser back disabled on one page only. I used for that `window.onpopstate = function (e) { window.history.forward(); };` it makes the browser back **disabled for all pages**, because when I go on other pages and click on browser back there also it makes browser back disabled but i want to make disabled only on one page. How is it possible to make browser back disabled for one page only and rest of that page for browser back enabled in Angular ?

notification-approved-by-id.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { StatusService } from '../service/status.service';
import { Notification } from '../classes/notification';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-notific-approved-by-id',
  templateUrl: './notific-approved-by-id.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./notific-approved-by-id.component.css']
})
export class NotificApprovedByIdComponent implements OnInit {

  notificationObj : Notification = new Notification();
  ngOnInit() {
    var em;
    this.statusService.getNotificationApprovedById(em).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        if(data != undefined && data.payload != undefined && data.status == 1){
          this.notificationObj = data.payload[0];
          window.onpopstate = function (e) { window.history.forward(); };
        }
      }
     );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to remove listeners while destroying the page

```js
export class NotificApprovedByIdComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(private statusService : StatusService,private router : Router) { }

const orig_onpopstate: any = window.onpopstate;
ngOnInit() {
  var em;
  this.statusService.getNotificationApprovedById(em).subscribe(
  (data) => {
    if(data != undefined && data.payload != undefined && data.status == 1){
      window.onpopstate = function (e) { window.history.forward(); };
    }
  });
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    window.onpopstate = orig_onpopstate;
}
```

Comment: it works but i click on browser back on more than 30 times that time it go again back,that time this think is not work

Comment: John,

You have to register onpopstate while your page load and when you go move away from that page (i.e either clicking on button or link) you have to unregister the onpopstate.

Comment: how, i can do this can u edit in code if possible bcoz i am not getting idea what r u saying

Comment: Can you please share your page code so I can modified and fixed your issue.